# What Illustrator effect was used to create this design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

How can I achieve the same effect on different forms? (in this case it is applied to the letter A, I want to apply it to other letter and shape).

[image]

The author of this work also has an animated version of this logo (white), I'd like to know how I can make a similar animation as well:
https://www.behance.net/gallery/10081139/archAssist

Comment: Hi Vasilyuk! Can you show what you have tried so far when trying to replicate that effect and explain the steps you used, and also post a screenshot of your tests? Unfortunately, StackExchange doesn't provide on-demand tutorials in this way but we can help with specific requests if you're stuck somewhere. Your animation question probably has answers already if you use the search field and look for animations on this Stack. If you can't find anything, then maybe the animation question should be asked as a new question with the proper tags (eg. software you want to use)!

Comment: I'd say this is done in Processing. I'd recommend the book "Generative Design" http://www.generative-gestaltung.de/about . Checkout chapter 4.3.1 "Graphic from pixel values". It will show you sample code of a similar design.

Answer (score 6):

My Solution is depending on Astute Graphics plugin called "[Phantasm](http://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/)" you can download a trial version of it.

First I have to prepare my artwork before using it. So please follow my steps.

1. type the letter A with your desire font.
2. convert the type to outline by selecting it with the black arrow and go to `Types > Create Outlines` or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
3. now I have to create an offset of that letter by selecting my artwork with the black arrow and go to `Object > Path > Offset Path` and adjust the value with the desire values.
4. ungroup the result and recolor the artwork with two colors one is dark and the other is lighter as the next screen shoot.

[image]

5. select the two paths with the black arrow and blend it, by going to `Object > Blend` or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and here you are the result.

[image]

6. draw a triangle and drag and drop it into the symbols panel as shown, and select it (very important to select it before you leave the symbols panel).

[image]

7. now it's time of the plugin, select `Effects > Phantasm > Halftone...` and adjust the values to the desire effect. as the hereunder screenshot.

[image]

[image]

in the dot properties make sure to select "Selected Symbol" from the shape droplist.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, I'm currently trying to apply them all to see how these solutions work!